# Cómo puedo bloquear una casilla de datos en QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

Estoy creando una calculadora electrónica en QT Creator, y dispongo de un combo box donde puedo seleccionar tipos de datos (entero, racional, dígito, ...) para poder compararlos, sumarlos, etc etc. La cosa es que alguno de ellos, pueden escribir por ejemplo la base y su longitud, pero hay otros que por ejemplo la longitud no se pone, por lo que se debería bloquear esa casilla.

Habría alguna forma de conseguirlo?

La programación es en C++.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Raul, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Answer (score 1):

Para ajustar el aspecto de la Gui en base a la seleccion de un combo box usa el evento currentIndexChanged del combo box y habilita o no cada elemento que desees, algo asi:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index) {

    switch(index) {
        case 0:         // Primer elemento del ComoBox
            ui->lineEdit->setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case 1:         // Segundo elemento del ComoBox
            ui->lineEdit->setEnabled(false);
            break;
    }

}
```